# Showing $B(s) - \frac{s}{t}B(t)$ is normal

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Given that $s<t$ and $\{B(t),t\geq 0\}$ is a standard brownian motion,
how would I show that $B(s) - \frac{s}{t}B(t)$ is normal? 
I tried doing something like
$$B(s) - \frac{s}{t}B(t) = 1/t (s(B(t)+B(s)) - (t-s)B(s))
$$
which doesn't result in anything.
Also, what does showing that $\mathrm{Cov}(B(s), -\frac{s}{t}B(t)) = -s^2/t \neq 0$ mean? I thought this would mean that $B(s), -\frac{s}{t}B(t)$ are not independent, meaning their sum won't gauranteed be normal.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the vector $(B(s),B(t))$ is normal?

Comment: No, how do you prove that? I only know that B(s) + B(t) will be normal (with mean 0 and variance 3s+t) for s<t

Comment: You can prove it by a) recalling the fact that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian process **or** b) using the fact that $B_t-B_s$ and $B_s$ are two independent Gaussian random variables.

Comment: Once I show that $B_t-B_s$ and $ B_s$ are independent, I can show that $(B_s,B_t)$ is normal since the linear combination $B_t-B_s + B_s$ is normal right? Which then means the linear combination   
$-\frac{s}{t}(B_ t - B_s) + (1-\frac{s}{t})B_s$ is normal?

Comment: That's correct, yes.

Comment: @Mr.BromwichI Feel free to write your reasoning as an answer to this question and accept it :)